# ASP.NET MVC 3 input name and id in lowerCamelCase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like the helpers in MVC to render all input tags with the name and id in lowerCamelCase. Is it possible to do?

Examel:
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FirstName)

Default: 
    `<intput type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />`

I would like: 
    `<intput type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom HTML helpers or extend existing ones. See: http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:creating-custom-html-helpers